# Get sku of selected custom option

Tags: custom-options, sku

I want SKU value of product's selected custom option on onepage.

Can somebody help me on this ?

Thank you.

Comment: need to cart page or product view page?

Comment: I need this on cart page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try bellow code

```
<?php
$options = $_item->getBuyRequest()->getData('options');

foreach ($options as $key => $value) {
     $optionData = $_item->getProduct()->getOptionById($key);
     if($optionData['type'] == 'drop_down') {
         foreach ($optionData->getValues() as $v) {
             if ($v['option_type_id'] == $value) {
                 echo $v->getSku();
                 echo "<br>";
                 break;
             }
         }
     }
     elseif ($optionData['type'] == 'field') {
       echo $optionData['sku'];   
     }

 }

?>
```

Comment: I have two custom options, first's input type is drop down and next is Field.Using your code I only get an sku value of custom option which is selected from field input type. But cannot getting sku of custom option selected from Drop down.

Comment: updated my answer. try that now.

Comment: updated my answer as per condition.

Comment: updated again for selected option condition.

Comment: any idea how to obtain the selected custom option from options.phtml?